# How to plot line to the trajectory

Tags: python, matplotlib

how to plot the line to trajectory

the original plot :
[image]
[image]

```
x=[]
x = np.arange(0,15000)
for i in range(0,2):
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
    plt.plot(x,FC_COP[0:15000,i],color='red')
    plt.plot(x,Pred_COP[0:15000,i],markerfacecolor='none',color='green')
    plt.title('COP Calculation (Training Data)')
    plt.ylabel(col_COP[i])
    plt.xlabel('Time(s)')
    plt.show()
```

I want to make it to trajectory like below:

[image]

I've try use below code to make the data to trajectory as above plot, but its not working.

```
x = range(15000)
y1 = FC_COP[:,0]
y2 = FC_COP[:,1]

pyplot.plot(x,y1)
pyplot.plot(x,y2)
pyplot.show()
```

the result is not what I want

[image]

Comment: Could you please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your plot suggests is that you want to plot `FC_COP[:,0]` vs `FC_COP[:,1]`

So, instead of using any time variable x, directly plot them against each other:

```
pyplot.plot(FC_COP[:,0],FC_COP[:,1])
pyplot.show()
```

As your dataset periodically returns to zero, this plot will look a bit ugly. To avoid that, you could filter out zero values first:

```
y1 = FC_COP[:,0]
y2 = FC_COP[:,1]
data_filter = abs(y1) > 0
pyplot.plot(y1[data_filter], y2[data_filter])
pyplot.show()
```

To show the trajectories of real and predicted values, add two plots:

```
real_x = FC_COP[:,0]
real_y = FC_COP[:,1]
predict_x = Pred_COP[:,0]
predict_y = Pred_COP[:,1]

data_filter = abs(real_x) > 0

pyplot.plot(real_x[data_filter], real_y[data_filter])
pyplot.plot(predict_x[data_filter], predict_y[data_filter])
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: how if I want make different color for y1 and y2? is it possible or not if I want make they different color

Comment: unfortunatelyI do not fully understand your final goal of what to plot. A tajectory is a single curve, so it cannot have to different colors. The two components (y1 and y2) are just the x and y coordinates of this trajectory. Or are you talking about the real and predicted value shown in your question? I'll try to update my answer accordingly.